# CMake set debugging enviroment for Debug and Release builds diffrently

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, environment-variables

When using different library paths for linking with CMake

```
add_executable(MyTarget ${SOURCE_FILES} ${INCLUDE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(MyTarget LINK_PRIVATE debug ${SOME_LIBRARY_DIR}/debug/*.lib )
target_link_libraries(MyTarget LINK_PRIVATE optimized ${SOME_LIBRARY_DIR}/release/*.lib )
```

and then wanting to execute it using the Debugger of MSVC, it cant start because it cant find the DLLs.

The DLLs are in `${SOME_BINARY_DIR}/debug` and `${SOME_BINARY_DIR}/release`. I tried to add both paths for Release and Debug to the debugger properties(Propeties->Debugging->Enviroment).
But with this

```
set_target_properties(MyTarget PROPERTIES VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT PATH=${SOME_BINARY_DIR}/debug)
set_target_properties(MyTarget PROPERTIES VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT PATH=${SOME_BINARY_DIR}/release)
```

the debug path gets overwritten by the relase path.

I tried alot with `$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug PATH=${SOME_BINARY_DIR}/debug>` but none of my attempts are working.
Is there a way to setup diffrent enviroments in VS Debugger with CMake?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself:

```
    set_target_properties(MyTarget PROPERTIES
        VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT 
"$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:PATH=${SOME_BINARY_DIR}/debug> \
 $<$<CONFIG:Release>:PATH=${SOME_BINARY_DIR}/release>"
    )
```